# Handling very fast moving objects in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an object that is moving very fast (max velocity 900). When it reaches max speed it starts to create trailing objects or motion blur.

But I just want it to be the object moving fast. I am running on 60 fps.

I like the speed of the object but I don't like how its getting rendered (motion blur). How do I handle this?

This object bounces all around the screen with a restitution of 1.02, because I want to make it pick up speed as it keeps bouncing. I want to make it go faster thats why I did the 1.02 restitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motion blur may simply be due to the LCD display having an "afterglow". So the position the object was in the previous frame is still a little brighter in the next frame because it takes some time for the crystals inside the LCD to return to the unlit state.

This causes "motion blur" on any moving object on the screen, and is of course more noticeable the faster the object moves. You may even be able to make out multiple versions of the same objects at different light levels trailing behind the object's position.

[image]

This effect may also depend somewhat on the device and model, and is often called 'ghosting'.

Regardless, there's nothing you can do about the "motion blur" caused by the LCD screen's afterglow effect. Here's a good [article explaining the effects and their causes](http://www.blurbusters.com/faq/lcd-motion-artifacts/).

Comment: accepted for very understandable explanation of my question. [ still watching your tutorials :) ]

Comment: Also keep in mind that motion blur is a correct artefact of sampling  real world motion. If your running at 60fps objects will look better with motion blur, if you were doing CGI for film (or TV) you would be going to great lengths to add correct motion blur to your objects. Without motion blur objects will stutter, although this is less noticeable as you increase the frame rate. Also note that the human eye also adds motion blur via persistence of vision, where an afterimage of what you see is persists on the retina for a fraction of a second, giving fast moving objects blur.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... you'll have trouble getting it to render smoothly.

At that speed (900 points per second) it will move 15 points every FRAME if running at 60 fps. That's a significant amount to move in such a short amount of time. In about 1/3 of a second it will travel entirely across the screen.

I'm guessing it will be getting to the limit of the ability of the hardware. Both the processor, the screen and your actual eyes. I imagine you'll also hit physics errors too with it possibly escaping through walls etc...

Can you show a video of how it is currently behaving?